# Adding row to DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

http://codepaste.net/ujhdq2

```
    private Connection Econn;
    private DefaultTableModel examTable = new DefaultTableModel();
    public StudentInfoFrame(int eid) {
        initComponents();
        this.e_id = eid;
        try
        {
            jTable2.getParent().setBackground(Color.black);
            SimpleDataSource.init();
            Econn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
            jTable2.setModel(examTable);
            retrieveExams();
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   

private void retrieveExams()
    {
        try
        {
            Statement stat = Econn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT date, name,forename,surname,status,Exam "+
            "FROM studentexam sx INNER JOIN Exam e ON sx.ex_id = e.ex_id " +
            "INNER JOIN employee em ON e.head = em.e_id WHERE st_id = "+this.e_id;
            ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery(query);
            if(result.first())
            {
            while(result.next())
            {
                String headname = result.getString("forename")+" "+result.getString("surname");
                String name = result.getString("name");
                int status = result.getInt("status");
                String pres;
                if(status == 1)
                {
                    pres = "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    pres = "No"; 
                }
                String exam;
                if(result.getInt("Exam") == 1)
                {
                    exam = "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    exam = "No";
                }
                Date date = result.getDate("date");
                int day = date.getDay();
                int year = date.getYear()+1900;
                int month = date.getMonth()+1;
                String datum = year+"-"+month+"-"+day; 
                int row = examTable.getRowCount()+1;
                examTable.insertRow(row, new Object[] { name,headname,datum, exam,pres });
            }
            }

        }
```

This gives me this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 > 0.

Any idea?

Comment: write your code here, don't link it.

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultTableModel#insertRow` inserts an entry at a given index. It is not possible to insert an entry beyond the model's current row count

Replace

```
examTable.insertRow(row, new Object[] { name,headname,datum, exam,pres });
```

with

```
examTable.addRow(new Object[] { name,headname,datum, exam,pres });
```

Look at these lines:

```
if (result.first()) {
   while(result.next()) {
```

Your `SQL` would suggest that you are expecting a single record to be returned from your query. However, by calling `ResultSet#first`, the cursor is advanced past the first possible row so your `while` loop is never entered. Instead you could replace these lines with:

```
if (result.next()) {
```

---

Aside from this, use a `PreparedStatement` rather than a `Statement` to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Somehow it does not give me any results.  No rows are being added. Also my table does not show itself when running the app.

Comment: See update. The issue of the table now showing itself could be a layout issue but I cannot comment on that as you have not included the code where it gets added.

Comment: The layout is fixed, yet I still see no entries (and yes the query actually gives entries). Ive followed your instructions correctly.

Comment: I'd say to place a breakpoint before `addRow` to make sure that you're entering the `if` statement scope and check the values being passed to the call itself.

Comment: Ive put a system out println in the else-statement if the resutl.next() returns false. For some reason it doesnt find any results, YET if I enter the query in my workbench it does give me multiple entries (with id 1).

Comment: If you havent already done so, try printing out `query`, copy and paste _exactly_ into workbench & run query.

Comment: Yes, the query really gives multiple entries.. So it's not about the entry.

Comment: I still have issues with this. I can't figure out how to put new rows with data in my table.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
int row = examTable.getRowCount()+1;
```

with

```
int row = examTable.getRowCount();
```

Everything is 0-based index in Java

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but unanswered. I signed up just for this.
Everytime you update(add, insert, delete) your Table Model:

```
examTable.addRow(new Object[] { name,headname,datum, exam,pres });
```

You need to refresh the table with the updated model:

```
jTable2.setModel(examTable);
```

This does not occur automatically in my experience.